# Windows 8 Grid App template | Edit Sample Data Source

Tags: c#

I just created a new windows 8 app using the Grid App template, and simply i wanted to add a new text block in my xaml code and bind some data to it on each item in the groups, how can I edit the data source and add the new item? my  code is as below:

```
 <XAML>

<TextBlock  x:Name="Contact" Text="{Binding Contact}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="471" Margin="1022,101,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="282" FontSize="15"/>


<C# - SampleDataSource>

public class SampleDataItem
{
    public SampleDataItem(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description, String content, String contact)
    {
        this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Subtitle = subtitle;
        this.Description = description;
        this.ImagePath = imagePath;
        this.Content = content;
        this.Contact = contact;
    }

public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
    public string Content { get; private set; }
    public string Contact { get; private set; }


{
                JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                group.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Description"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Contact"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Content"].GetString()));
            }
```

NOTE : I already skipped any C# code that's not related here.. when I run the code i get an exception that says KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code and referring to this line of code by a drawn line:
 var sampleDataGroups = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupsAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you initialize/set the valze of `itemValue`? Did you make sure that this item contains all the keys you want to access?